# C# delegate server client example

Tags: c#, delegates

I have been trying to get my head around delegates in C#, but I just don't seem to get the point how to use them.

I have a program that should do the following with delegates:

Main.cs:

- Create 1 server;
- Create 3 clients;
- Register clients to server;
- Send message from server to all registered clients;
- Unregister 1 client and send message from server to registered clients;
- Send message from server to specific client.

Server.cs:

- `public delegate MsgSend(string message);`
- `private MsgSend msgSend;`
- `public void Register(MsgSend m);`
- `public void Unregister(MsgSend m);`
- `public void SendMessage(string message);`

Clien.cs:

- `private string id;`
- `public Client(string id);` - explicit constructor;
- `public void ClientRegister(Server server);`
- `public void ClientUnregister(Server server);`
- `public void PrintMessage(string message);`

How should I use the delegate int this situation...?

Any help with some explanations how and where things are happening in this program will be in great use for me.

Thanks in advance.

---

Here is the code:

Server:

```
public delegate string MsgSend(string message);

class Server
{
    private MsgSend msgSend;

    public void Register(MsgSend m)
    { // Is this the right way to use the delegate as multicast delegate
      // to register the client and say it is registered or 
      // I should do extremely different thing here?
        msgSend += new MsgSend(m);
        m("xx");
    }

    public void Unregister(MsgSend m)
    { // Is this the right way to use the delegate as multicast delegate
      // to register the client and say it is registered or 
      // I should do extremely different thing here?
        msgSend += new MsgSend(m);
        m("yy");
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message + this.msgSend);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
class Client
{
    public string id;

    public Client(string id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void ClientRegister(Server server)
    {
        server.Register(...); // What should I pass as parameter here and why...
    }

    public void ClientUnregister(Server server)
    {
        server.Unregister(...); // What should I pass as parameter here and why...
    }

    public void PrintMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id + " recieved: " + message);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { // Is this enough in the main program so the program to work?
        Server svr = new Server();

        Client cl1 = new Client("123");
        Client cl2 = new Client("456");
        Client cl3 = new Client("789");

        cl1.ClientRegister(svr);
        cl2.ClientRegister(svr);
        cl3.ClientRegister(svr);

        svr.SendMessage("message from server");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is full working code:

**Main**

```
using System;

static partial class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Server svr = new Server();

        Client cl1 = new Client("123");
        Client cl2 = new Client("456");
        Client cl3 = new Client("789");

        // Register
        cl1.ClientRegister(svr);
        cl2.ClientRegister(svr);
        cl3.ClientRegister(svr);

        svr.SendMessage("message from server");

        // Unregister    
        cl1.ClientUnregister(svr);
        cl2.ClientUnregister(svr);
        cl3.ClientUnregister(svr);

        // Try send string when you unregistered all clients
        svr.SendMessage("message from server again");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
class Server
{
    public delegate void MsgSend(string message);

    private MsgSend msgSend;

    public void Register(MsgSend m)
    {
        msgSend += m;
        m("Registered");
    }

    public void Unregister(MsgSend m)
    {
        msgSend -= m; // <--- Change += to -=
        m("Unregistered");
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        //You have to check if msgSend is null:
        if (msgSend != null) this.msgSend(message);
        else Console.WriteLine("DONT HAVE ANY CLIENT!");
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
class Client
{
    public string id;

    public Client(string id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void ClientRegister(Server server)
    {
        server.Register(PrintMessage);
    }

    public void ClientUnregister(Server server)
    {
        server.Unregister(PrintMessage); 
    }

    public void PrintMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client " + id + " recieved: " + message);
    }
}
```

When run `Main()` you will receive:

```
Client 123 recieved: Registered
Client 456 recieved: Registered
Client 789 recieved: Registered
Client 123 recieved: message from server
Client 456 recieved: message from server
Client 789 recieved: message from server
Client 123 recieved: Unregistered
Client 456 recieved: Unregistered
Client 789 recieved: Unregistered
DONT HAVE ANY CLIENT!
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sakura. Works perfekt.